# how can i fix addr is not defined in python

Tags: python, sockets

I want to make a app like traceroute. I am trying to find routers IP adresses which i passed until i reach the machine and save them in my rota file. But i am taking addr is not defined error. I searched , usually they are giving addr = None but this is causing -'NoneType' object is not subscriptable- error. How can i fix it ?

This is my code:

```
import sys
import socket

dst = sys.argv[1]
dst_ip = socket.gethostbyname(dst)
f = open("rota.txt","w")
timeout = 0.2
max_hops = 30
ttl=1
port = 11111

while True:
    receiver = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_RAW,proto=socket.IPPROTO_ICMP)
    receiver.settimeout(timeout)
    receiver.bind(('',port))

    sender = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET,type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM,proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_IP, socket.IP_TTL, ttl)
    sender.sendto(b'',(dst_ip,port))


    try:
        data, addr = receiver.recvfrom(512)
        f.write('\n' + str(addr[0]))
    except socket.error:
        pass

    finally:
        receiver.close()
        sender.close()

    ttl += 1
    if ttl > max_hops or addr[0] == dst_ip:
        break
```

And my errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rota.py", line 33, in <module>
    if ttl > max_hops or addr[0] == dst_ip:
NameError: name 'addr' is not defined
```

Comment: You're getting an error on the `recvfrom` call, so `addr` never gets defined

Comment: Don't suppress the error raised, print it out at least.